# A div that goes outside its parent

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an HTML layout. Inside the content div (`#contenido-post`) there are various divs of the same class (`.division-categorias`). The problem is that the last `.division-categorias` spills outside its parent and overlaps the sidebar (`#columna-izquierda`).

Here is the [example](http://nicolasgolub.com/html/categorias.html).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are adding a closing div tag in the **last 2 categories** of class **"division-categorias"**
Take a look at the lines with the image tag

```
  <img src="imagenes/categorias-thumbnail.png" width="204" height="150" /></div>
```

Are you sure you want to close the div tag there?

Comment: sory @Steve. I was not aware of your answer. I'm agree with you and I belive the problem is with this not intentional closing div I am addressing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you actually taken a look at the HTML in the browser?  It looks like the `.division-categorias` are not inside the same div, but continuously move out one level.  My best guess is that you are creating these divs in some sort of loop on the server and are adding an extra closing `</div>` somewhere.